# Java Filter to remove untrust character is causing issue

Tags: java, spring-security

I have added filter to remove untrust character(<,>) in application.But this filter is giving "Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled" issue

My filter is like this,

```
  private FilterConfig filterConfig;
  static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

      public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
        super((HttpServletRequest)request);
      }

    /**
 Method used to remove the unsafe characters(<,>,(,),%) from parameter values
*/
      public String getParameter(String paramName) {
        String value = removeUntrustChars(super.getParameter(paramName));
        return value;
      }

/**
 Method used to remove the unsafe characters(<,>,(,),%) from parameter values
*/
      public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {

        String values[] = super.getParameterValues(paramName);
        if(values != null && values.length >0){
           for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
              if(values[index] != null && values[index].length()>0){
                 values[index] = removeUntrustChars(values[index]);
              }
            }
        }
        return values;
      }
      
/**
 Method used to remove the unsafe characters(<,>,(,),%) from cookie values
*/
      public Cookie[] getCookies(){
      
        Cookie[] cookies = super.getCookies();
         Integer len=cookies!=null? cookies.length:0;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                cookies[i].setValue(removeUntrustChars(cookies[i].getValue()));
            }
            return cookies;
      }
      

/**
 Method used to remove the unsafe characters(<,>,(,),%) from given String. 
*/
      private String removeUntrustChars(String value)
          {
                if(value != null && value.length()>0)
                {
           value = value.replaceAll(">","&gt");
           value = value.replaceAll("<","&lt");
                   value = value.replaceAll("\"","&quot"); 
                   value = value.replaceAll("\'","&quot"); 
                   value = value.replaceAll(";"," ");  
                   value = value.replaceAll("-"," "); 
        }  
                return value;
      }
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){
      this.filterConfig=filterConfig;
      System.out.println("init() method has been get invoked");
  }

  public void doFilter (ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) {

    try{
       // Wrapping the request object using custom wrapper
        RequestFilter.FilteredRequest filteredRequest= new RequestFilter.FilteredRequest(request);
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        
//boolean flag=Boolean.FALSE;
//         flag=req.getRequestURI().contains("resource") || req.getRequestURI().contains("img") || req.getRequestURI().contains("favicon");
//        System.out.println("doFilter() method has been get invoked:"+req.getRequestURI()+"flag---" +flag);
//        if(!flag) {
            System.out.println("called---"+req.getRequestURI());
        chain.doFilter(filteredRequest, response);
//        }
    }
    catch (IOException io){
      System.out.println("IOException raised");
    }
    catch (ServletException se)
    {
      System.out.println("ServletException raised");
    }
  }

  public FilterConfig getFilterConfig()
  {
    return this.filterConfig;
  }

  public void setFilterConfig (FilterConfig filterConfig)
  {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
  }
  public void destroy(){
  }
```

i  have added filter to remove untrust character(<,>) in application.But this filter is giving "Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled" issue

Comment: *But this filter is giving ...* That doesn't really make sense. What do you mean "giving"? Also do ```printStackTrace``` on your exceptions

Comment: When I add filter to application , On loading of login page it's not taking any of the css files it's showing "Refused to apply style from -- because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled"

Comment: I think we'd need to see the filter. Please put it in the question

Comment: Again, that filter should be using `printStackTrace`. Then please post *full stack trace* **as code**

Comment: Please note, I'm not getting any exception but the problem is only the CSS not working.